# Breaking string list in different columns

Tags: c#, linq, list, listview, c#-4.0

I have string list like that

```
<tr><td>id:1, col: a, val: 1</tr></td>
<tr><td>id:2, col: b, val: 2</tr></td>
<tr><td>id:3, col: c, val: 3;col: d, val: 4;col: e, val: 5</tr></td>
```

I am creating a table as

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   @foreach (var item in (List<string>)TempData["tableList"])
      {
        @Html.Raw(item.ToString())
      }
</table>
```

I have three columns i.e `id, col, val` with values.

The problem is that in some the columns are repeated with values which are seperated by `';'` and i want to display those repeated columns in different line like this.

```
<tr><td>id:1, col: a, val: 1</tr></td>
<tr><td>id:2, col: b, val: 2</tr></td>
<tr><td>id:3, col: c, val: 3</tr></td>
      <tr><td>col: d, val: 4</tr></td>
      <tr><td>col: e, val: 5</tr></td>
```

Can anoyone suggest me how to break the list like i wanted to show.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Replace(";", '"</td></tr><tr><td>")`

```
@foreach (var item in (List<string>)TempData["tableList"])
{
    @Html.Raw(item.ToString().Replace(";", "</td></tr><tr><td>"))
}
```

You can check [.net Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PEQ5vi)

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach (var item in (List<string>)TempData["tableList"])
    {
     if (item.Contains(";"))
        {
            foreach (var arrayitem in item.Split(';')) {
                @Html.Raw("<tr><td>"+ arrayitem.ToString().Replace("<tr><td>","").Replace("</td></tr>","")+ "</td></tr>")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw(item.ToString())
        }
}
Try this and check your <td><tr> should be close and open and close accordingly.And at Controller Side use like this: List<string> tableList = new List<string>();
        tableList.Add("<tr><td>id:1, col: a, val: 1</td></tr>");
        tableList.Add("<tr><td>id:1, col: a, val: 1</td></tr>");
        tableList.Add(" <tr><td> id:3, col: c, val: 3; col: d, val: 4; col: e, val: 5 </td></tr>");
        TempData["tableList"] = tableList;
```